# I get cuda-blas error when I run the python3 command directly. But the error dosent come when I use sudo with it

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

When I am running the model training code as a user and not as a root, I am getting the below mentioned error but when I run the command as root The code works perfectly.

2019-05-15 08:14:08.434048: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2019-05-15 08:14:08.691205: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1432] Found device 0 with properties:
name: Tesla P40 major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.531
pciBusID: dbd6:00:00.0
totalMemory: 22.38GiB freeMemory: 22.21GiB
2019-05-15 08:14:08.691284: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1511] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2019-05-15 08:14:09.000931: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:982] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2019-05-15 08:14:09.001004: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:988]      0
2019-05-15 08:14:09.001021: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1001] 0:   N
2019-05-15 08:14:09.001475: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 21544 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Tesla P40, pci bus id: dbd6:00:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2019-05-15 08:14:14.983797: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:464] failed to create cublas handle: CUBLAS_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED
2019-05-15 08:14:14.995585: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:464] failed to create cublas handle: CUBLAS_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED
2019-05-15 08:14:15.007580: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:464] failed to create cublas handle: CUBLAS_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED
2019-05-15 08:14:15.019390: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:464] failed to create cublas handle: CUBLAS_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED
2019-05-15 08:14:15.031163: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:464] failed to create cublas handle: CUBLAS_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED
2019-05-15 08:14:15.042872: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:464] failed to create cublas handle: CUBLAS_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED